# C# WebClient for Server Side Facebook Interaction

Tags: c#, facebook, iis, webclient

Using the c# System.Net.WebClient object I am able to successfully interact with the Facebook API.

Does anyone know if this is leanest / most efficient way of achieving server side interaction with Facebook with c# .NET Version 4?

Also, I read that there is a limit on WebClient connections... which apparently can be increased using the following in my web.config (this example increases the limit to 100)

```
<connectionManagement>
    <add address="*" maxconnection="100" />
</connectionManagement>
```

But, is that limit for all IIS requests or per each IIS request... in other words if I have 10 'simultaneous' page requests then would that mean my web server is allowed to open 100 or 1000 WebClient connections.